# MapField overlap with other screen

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-jde

```java
images = _appData.getImageAccoToScr("StoreLocaterMapView");
//Add Title Bar to Screen
addTitle();
// initializing the Map component
mMapField =  new CustomMapField(BLANK, null, _appData, getGraphics(), hFM);
// Adding button to toggle to store list view
addToggleButton();
/*// initializing the Map component
mMapField = new CustomMapField(BLANK, null, _appData, getGraphics(), hFM);    */

// Manager to add the components
_contentOne = new VerticalFieldManager(Color.WHITE | NO_HORIZONTAL_SCROLL | NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL | NON_FOCUSABLE);

// adding pins related to stores to map view
addPinsToMap();

//Add WaitingPopUp to screen
addPopup();


// adding manager to screen
_contentOne.add(mMapField);
add(_contentOne);
```

Here is the main code for adding map and one horizonatalmanager. when i scroll the map field it's overlap with manager.

Comment: Any body can answer me....

Answer (score 0):

have you try to add that map to manager ?

mainmanager.add(your hrizontal manager)
mainmanager.add(your manager that include the map)

add(mainmanager)